# How do I implement a recursive list in Haskell and methods to operate on it

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to create a method in Haskell which I would think is very intuitive.  I have a list of lists [of lists]* that is arbitrarily deep.  I'd like to pull out a specific atom in the list regardless of the depth of the recursion.  Here's my effort:

```
type List = [Array]
data Array = Int | List

drill :: Array -> [Int] -> Array
drill xs (index:[]) = xs !! index
drill xs (index:is) = drill (xs !! index) is
```

However I receive the following when loading in ghci:

```
drill.hs:5:23:
Couldn't match expected type `[Array]' with actual type `Array'
In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `xs'
In the expression: xs !! index
In an equation for `drill': drill xs (index : []) = xs !! index
```

What I've written seems intuitive to me but clearly Haskell is having type issues.  And as a Haskell newbie, I'm not the best at interpreting type errors.  I would think that the return type of the function could be either an atom: `Int`, or a list:`[Int]`.  Can anybody help me decipher this and suggest a solution?

Comment: That's not a list, that's a tree!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you say

```
data Array = Int | List
```

this doesn't mean "any `Int` is an `Array`, and any `List` is an `Array`". It instead means that `Array` has two constructors, `Int` and `List`, both of which take no arguments. The confusion arises from the fact that they have the same name as types; they're not related to the types beyond sharing a name. That is, your declaration is basically the same as

```
data Array = Foo | Bar
```

Instead, we need to give explicit constructor names for each alternative:

```
type List = [Array]
data Array = Elem Int | Nest List

drill :: Array -> [Int] -> Array
drill xs [] = xs
drill (Nest xs) (index:is) = drill (xs !! index) is
```

This means that `Elem` takes an `Int` and returns an `Array`, and `Nest` takes a `List` and returns an `Array`. We have to adjust the `drill` function to explicitly take the list of `Arrays` out of the `Nest` case.

The error you're getting is basically saying that you're trying to use `xs` as a list, but it's an `Array`. This is because you didn't pattern-match on it at all: just tried to use your argument (an `Array`) directly as a list.

Note that you'll still have to explicitly pattern-match on the result of `drill` to tell whether it's a single element or a nested list. There's no way to make a type whose values can literally *be* either integers or nested lists in Haskell; Haskell's unions are *tagged* (i.e. the constructors are explicit), and it has no subtyping.

For more information, I suggest reading [this introduction to algebraic data types](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) from [*Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).